# Python how to get folder name in registry

Tags: python, windows, registry, directory

i want to get the folder name of a path in the registry, not the key value!

I can already read a key value, so how do i read a folder value?

I want it because i need the version nr. of libreOffice,its only stored in the folder name.

```
def getRegistryKeyValue (self, root, dir, key):
       currentKey = winreg.OpenKey(root, dir)
       currentVersion, valuetype = winreg.QueryValueEx(currentKey, key)

key = self.getRegistryKeyFolder(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\LibreOffice")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [EnumKey](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.EnumKey) to iterate over "folders" (called "keys" in the registry)

```
parentKey = winreg.OpenKey(root, dir)
i = 0
while True:
   try:
       key = winreg.EnumKey(parent, i)
       print key
       i += 1
   except WindowsError: 
       break
```

Comment: I linked to the docs... but I've added sample now. Hope it helps